# Implementing restrictions based query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a query in ElasticSearch (Nest) where only documents that meet certain restrictions are returned. Each document will have an array of strings (Restrictions), and the query will also be given an array of strings (let's call this "satisfiedRestrictions") and the goal is to retrieve (filter out) only those documents that ONLY have the restrictions specified in the "satisfiedRestrictions"

Lets say I have documents

```
[
 {
  "Id":1,
  "Restrictions":["restriction1", "restriction2"]
 },
 {
  "Id":2,
  "Restrictions":["restriction1"]
 },
 {
  "Id":3,
  "Restrictions":["restriction1", "restriction2", "restriction3"]
 }
]
```

Given `satisfiedRestrictions = ["restriction1", "restriction2"]` the query should return documents with Ids 1 and 2. Document 3 has an extra restriction ("restriction3") not specified in the `satisfiedRestrictions` parameter so this should be excluded from the results.

It would be possible to solve this with `must_not` clause (must not match "restiction3") but this would assume that all possible values for restrictions should be held somewhere. Ideal solution would be without having to do this.

Is there a good way to achieve this or is this kind of "restrictions-based" model not resolvable?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have distinct values in your array, this should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "terms" : { "Restrictions" : ["restriction1", "restriction2"] }
      },
      "must" : {
        "script" : {
          "script" : {
            "inline" : "doc[\"Restrictions\"].length < 3",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

edited: == 2 remplaced by < 3

Comment: Wouldn't this leave out document 2 in my example as that document has a single restriction (does not have "restriction2")?

Comment: This probably does not work when I have a 4th document with ```"Restrictions":["restriction1", "restriction3"]``` as it fulfills both conditions:

1) Has one of the specified restrictions
2) Has less than 3 restrictions.
But it also has the "restriction3" that is not one of the specified restrictions (the so called "satisfiedRestrictions")

Comment: yeah (i am tired), sadly i would go for a script then:     "filter": {
      "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
           "inline": "for(int i = 0; i < doc['Restrictions'].length; i++) { if (doc['Restrictions'][i] != "restriction1" || doc['Restrictions'][i] != "restriction2") { return false; } } return true;"
      }
    }
if you dont have millions of documents performance should be ok.